# Drawing Lines and Rectangle through mouse over an image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I implemented the copy image from clipboard to web page with the help of following tutorial :

http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/

Demo : www.pasteshack.net

It working properly.

Now I want to implement drawing shapes like lines, rectangles and circles over that image using jquery. I want it through mouse so that I can drag and drop it anywhere over image. The rectangles and circle must have to be transparent so that I can place it over image for identifying bug or fault in image.

Can it possible using jquery or javascript. Is there any plugin or tutorial available for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: html5 canvas element is best for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Following tutorial:

https://github.com/websanova/wPaint

It will definatly help you.